# iPhone WebApp GeoLocation

Tags: iphone, geolocation

I'm testing GeoLocation on iPhone. The ideia is to have a WebApp that runs on iPhone and, based on my location, gives-me the shortest path to well known spots in my city/country.

My current position os always the starting point.
The end point is always the nearest spot.

Imagine my known spots as all Train Stations in my city.

How can i do such thing? I guess i'll use google maps api but where do i define the spots? How can i say to google to trace the route to the nearest spot?

Thank u ALL:

Answer (score 0):

I hope, you are  going to show the route between two latitude & longitude values.The [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920582/how-to-draw-lines-on-a-google-maps) will help you..